# Can I make a parameter optional in a Typescript definition and function call?

Tags: typescript

Here is my call:

```
this.enumService.getData('ContentStatus'),
```

It's giving an error as my definition is:

```
getData(controller: any, params: any);
```

The function looks like this:

```
getData = (controller, params) => {
    if (!params) { params = "" }
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
```

How can I fix the definition and the function so a null is allowed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For your case the declaration `?`:

```
getData(controller: any, params?: any);
```

And if you are defining in TypeScript you can use default parameters `=`:

```
getData = (controller, params = "") => {
    var defer = this.$q.defer();
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation can be found on the typescript following construction`function create(name: string, animalOptions?: AnimalOptions): Animal;` use "?"

Comment: How about the function? Can I make it optional there also?